# Datatables: Javascript combine two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I try to combine two functions in JavaScript to work with datatables, but it doesn't work.

How can I combine both functions in JavaScript so that they both work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cx_data').DataTable( {
        order: [[ 2, 'desc' ], [ 0, 'asc' ]],
        "ordering": false,
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json",

        }

    } );
} );
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cx_data').DataTable( {
        "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
            if ( data[5].replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 > 150000 ) {
                $('td', row).eq(5).addClass('highlight');
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

Every hint is appreciated.
I've already spent hours trying to figure it out, but without success.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Move `createdRow` option to other config object and get rid of the second call to `DataTable. You are initializing the plugin twice

Comment: So did you try to combine them into one call by adding the item to the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine both the things at one place like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#cx_data').DataTable( {
         order: [[ 2, 'desc' ], [ 0, 'asc' ]],
         "ordering": false,
         "language": {
            "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json",
          },
          "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
           if ( data[5].replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 > 150000 ) {
               $('td', row).eq(5).addClass('highlight');
          }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Harshketu. I simply missed a comma!